# Why does r_[r_] hang?

Tags: python, numpy

This must be one of the shortest numpy hangs possible.
Please don't ask why on earth I even tried this.

```
from numpy import r_
r_[r_]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P60oP1chrzS3oFIhM7cgv6hEoSieqyg@uig@9v9/AA)

Is this the correct behaviour (and if so: why?) or a bug?

Comment: you can use a debugger to see where it hangs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is an interesting oddity you've found! It gets stuck for the same reason that `list(r_)` hangs, it's essentially in an infinite loop trying to iterate an infinite iterable.

Since [an object which implements `__getitem__` is considered iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable), `r_` is iterable, yielding `r_[0]`, `r_[1]`, `r[2]`... etc

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> it = iter(np.r_)
>>> next(it)
array([0])
>>> next(it)
array([1])
>>> next(it)
array([2])
>>> next(it)
array([3])
...
```

Note that `r_[obj]` iterates `obj` ([source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.21.4/numpy/lib/index_tricks.py#L344)) so `r_[r_]` will iterate itself indefinitely.

Comment: What's interesting to me is that the `AxisConcatenator` class has another method `def __len__(self): return 0`. Intuitively I would think it makes `r_` and iterable of size 0.

Comment: The [iterator protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types) does not consider `__len__`.

Comment: `AxisConcatenator` doesn't use the current `__iter__`/`__next__` protocol though, so it must be using the older `__getitem__` protocol "with `Sequence` semantics" (https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable). It appears a `Sequence` also needs to define `__len__`, but I guess stopping iteration at `__len__()` isn't guaranteed (https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence).

Comment: @BatWannaBe Actually it does, in a way - the object returned by `iter(r_)` (i.e. the _iterator_) is the one which adheres to the iterator protocol. The type does not need to be a sequence, nor does it need to define `__len__` in order to be _iterable_ via `__getitem__`.